# Visual Studio graying wrong #ifdef'd passages in C/C++ code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm working on a large, inherited C++ (really, mostly C) project developed and maintained under Visual Studio 2008. Technically, in Visual Studio terms, it is a "solution" consisting of eight "projects", and therein appears to be the rub.

As I'm sure most of you know, Visual Studio grays out the code that it believes to be #ifdef'd out. What I'm finding, though, is that it doesn't seem to do this correctly for the different projects. To keep matters simple, let's just call them Proj1, Proj2, ... Proj8. When I'm working on the Win32 Debug configuration of Proj5, I'd expect that the macros defined in the C/C++ Preprocessor properties configuration of Proj5 would determine what is grayed (or at least that there would be some straightforward way to make it so). Instead, I seem to be seeing views based on properties of Proj1. That is, if Proj1 defines some preprocessor macros that eliminate part of the code, I'm seeing that part grayed even when I'm working on Proj5. And the macros for Proj5 have no effect at all on what I see.

Yes, I did a complete clean and build (several, actually, and even saved everything off to SVN and started in a new top-level folder), and so I'm pretty sure this is not because of some vestigial files produced by an old build. And I'm pretty sure that in other respects Visual Sourcesafe "understands" the context correctly, because (1) the Build menu contains options related to Proj5, not Proj1; (b) at the bottom of the Project menu is "Proj5 properties..." not "Proj1 properties..."; and (c) there is no question that the #ifdef's are working in the program that is built: there are major feature differences, and they are as I'd expect them to be.

---

ADDED 27 Sept 2010 I still don't have an answer, so let me try this a different way: Assuming I've already run successful builds (which I have) is there *anything* other than the preprocessor properties and configuration of the currently selected project (and, as noted below, those of individual files, but that is moot in this case) that should influence what code is grayed?

Answer (score 1):

Please see if these preprocessor directives might be set for the individual *files*.  You can do this by right-clicking on a source file and selecting "Properties" from the context menu.  It's somewhat counterintuitive to think that the directives can be set for individual files, not just for projects.

If that doesn't help, your best bet might be to use a text editor to look for the problem preprocessor definitions in each of the project files to try to get a better idea of what might be happening.

Comment: Nope (with reference to the preprocessor directives). Good thought, and if it had been the case I could have missed it, but no preprocessor properties are set at the level of individual files.

Comment: I've long since gotten in there with jEdit and had a look at the project files. I didn't find anything, but I can't swear I couldn't have overlooked anything. I'd love to know what someone thinks I might look for.

Comment: Could there be an intermediate file that Visual Studio can't modify because it's checked into source control?  Or would the problem go away if you manually delete all of the intermediate files and restart VS?  You have probably already considered both of these.

Comment: My source control is SVN, so all files are freely modifiable. I would see (via symbols shown in Tortoise SVN) that the file is diverging from the last committed version, but (unlike what is typical with VSS) files would not be read-only on the Dev machine. So, no that can't be what is happening

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 is supposed to help with this.  In VS2008, the no-compile browse cache is done after preprocessing, so it can accommodate only one set of macro definitions.

I don't believe that "Build Clean" or "Rebuild" will delete the .ncb files, since they are not part of the build process at all.  I do know that deleting these files by hand fixes all kinds of weird behavior, but I'm afraid that in your case it's not going to be a lasting solution (the .ncb files will still get filled in based on a single configuration.)

Comment: Ah well. If the people I'm doing this project for ever decide to upgrade to VS2010, I'll see if you're right...

Answer (score 0):

Make the project the Startup Project and Remove and Re-add the offending Preprocessor Definition

Details: 
I found a process that that fixes my MFC projects when this happens (at least temporarily).  First I set the project I am working on as the startup project.  Do that by right-clicking the project in the solution explorer and selecting Set as Startup Project.  Then I go into the preprocessor definitions for the project and deleting the one that is not triggering and clicking OK.  You will see a little progress bar a few seconds later appear in the lower right. Once it finishes, go back into preprocessor definitions for the project and add it back in again and click OK.  After the little progress bar finishes again, you should see the correct code active again.

Comment: This particular project is so far in the past (about 5 years) that I have no way of checking whether that would have fixed my problem. Unsurprisingly, it's a while now since I've even used Visual Studio 2008. But thanks for the answer, and I hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In a very old project, the customer is forced to use VS2008 and stay with the same release. After having unsuccessfully tried all the above, my attempts have been:

1. Clean the solution, unload the project and reload it. This made VS
   properly gray areas but, sadly, the compiler was still generating
   errors and warning about the shaded code. So this one did not work
   either
2. **Stop using precompiled headers** has been the solution for me.
   Now it takes ages to compile, but the code is correctly generated

To do that, go to the `Solution Explorer`, right-click on the project, select `Properties`. Open `Configuration Properties`, then `C/C++` and `Precompiled Headers`. Select `Not Using Precompiled Headers` for the `Create/Use Precompiled Header` property. Now apply and save. New builds will honour the macros and definitions

Comment: Given that your recent response: It's over 13 years since I asked this. Not only am I long done with that particular project (as noted in my comment on @WebmasterJeff's 2015 remark), I'm retired, as is the code base in question, which was completely replaced in a subsequent version of the system. I sincerely hope no one these days is stuck using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I also thought that I would never have to use such an ancillary environment in 2023, but the customer forced us to do that. I wanted to share my resolution, in case somebody else is thrown into the same arena.